# Problem mapping my JSPs in a SpringBoot app

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, jsp

First of all , i have a header and footer set to show on all my jsp pages. 
The landing page is mapped as "/".
The first link in footer is mapped as "/recrutement".
The second link in footer is mapped as "/service".
Inside recrutement.jsp (first footer link) i have a link mapped to "/annonce".
When i am on annonce.jsp the url is http://localhost:8080/recrutement/annonce. until here everything is fine.
But while on annonce.jsp , if i click the second footer link , the url ends up like http://localhost:8080/recrutement/annonce/service instead of just http://localhost:8080/service...

I think there may be an error in my mapping? or perhaps with viewResolver?
Thanks for your help

All 3 concerned Controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class AccueilController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String showAccueil(Model theModel, HttpSession session) {
        ...
        return "index";
    }
}





@Controller
@RequestMapping("/recrutement")
public class RecrutementController {

    @Autowired
    private JobOfferRepository jor;

    @GetMapping(path = "")
    public String showRecrutement(Model theModel) {
        List<JobOffer> ajo = jor.findAll();
        theModel.addAttribute("jobOfferList", ajo);
        return "recrutement";
    }


    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public String showJobOffer(Model theModel, @PathVariable int id){
        JobOffer jo = jor.findById(id).get();
        theModel.addAttribute("jobOffer", jo);
        return "recrutementAnnonce";
    }
}






@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StaticPagesController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/services")
    public String showServices() {
        return "services";
    }
}
```

My footer html:

```
</div> <--- opening div located at end of header


    <div class="middle" >
        <div class="block">
            <span class="title">Services Orvif</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="services">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <span class="title">Nous contacter</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="recrutement">Recrutement</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

recrutement jsp:

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
<h1 id="carreerTitle">Carri&egrave;re</h1>

<ul id="listJob">
    <c:forEach items="${jobOfferList}" var="career">
        <li>
            <p>${career.jobTitle}</p>
            <a href="/recrutement/${career.id}" class="button red-blue">Voir l'annonce</a>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>

<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

recrutementAnnonce jsp (nothing of interest in my opinion besides the included footer at bottom:

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
<div id="descriptionJob">
    <h2>
        Description du poste
    </h2>
    <p>${jobOffer.jobDescription}</p>
</div>
<div id="listMissionJob">
    <h2>Vos missions</h2>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach items="${jobOffer.jobMissionsById}" var="mission">
            <li><span class="circleRed"></span>${mission}
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>

<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

Comment: class StaticPagesController  remove @RequestMapping("/"), showServices() method above add  @RequestMapping(value = "/service", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jose, but after aplying the changes, the problem remains